# Problem with filtering array, When trying to filter data with search and from dropdown in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <span v-if="isLoaded" class="select">
      <select v-model="selectNum" name="text">
        <option value="" selected="selected">status</option>
        <option value="ok">ok</option>
        <option value="notok">notok</option>
        <option value="medium">medium</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="search-wrapper">
      <span class="bar">
        <input
          type="text"
          v-model="search"
          placeholder="filter"
          class="s-bar"
        />
      </span>
    </span>
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      {{ user.name }}
      <div v-for="list in lists" :key="list.id">
        {{ list.pan }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { userdata } from "../assets/userdata";
import { listdata } from "../assets/listdata";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data: function () {
    return {
      users: userdata,
      lists: listdata,
      search: "",
      isLoaded: false,
      selectNum: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.isLoaded = true;
  },
  computed: {
    sourceInfo() {
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
        return 0;
      }
      const res = this.userList
        .filter((user) => {
          return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        })
        .sort(compare);
      if (this.selectNum) {
        return res.filter((user) => user.status === this.selectNum);
      }
      return res;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Initially the user data will be loaded completely. Later based on two filters, i.e., One for search filter, I should filter the array out of all user array. second one, for drop down based on status in User array, I need to filter the array.

How do i make my code changes in order to work it correctly. at present it is not filtering the array either from search or from dropdown. But just displaying the data.

Comment: Are you building this for a production app with many users & a multitude of devices or is this a hobby project?

Comment: No i am just learning the vuejs and practicing.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple changes required to make this example functioning.

First, you need to update what you are displaying. Instead of the list that you have now, I suggest to just print out the variable `sourceInfo`, which will contain the filtered list. Therefore, add somewhere to the HTML part

```
{{ sourceInfo }}
```

After this change, you should already get an error message in the console, because the content of `sourceInfo` is now in use and thus, finally evaluated. The message goes something around:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.userList is undefined"
```

So, you need to change `this.userList` to `this.users` which is an actual variable and contains the list of users:

```
const res = this.users.filter((user) => ...
```

And another error pops up:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: user.name.toLowerCase().includes(...).sort is not a function"
```

This one comes from applying the `sort()` function on a `boolean`, which is expected to be returned by the `includes()` function. Thus, as a last step,  remove the `sort()` part of the filter which checks that the user matches the text search criteria, and apply it before returning the result:

```
const res = this.users.filter((user) => {
  return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
});

...

return res.sort(compare);
```

The basic functionality should work by now. When checking your filters of the dropdown, you might notice that for `nok` an empty array is returned even though one user has the corresponding status. This comes from the fact, that the dropdown element `nok` has the value `notok` assigned. Therefore, by simply changing the value to `nok` you're good to go.

```
<option value="nok">nok</option>
```

Here is the link to a codesandbox of the running code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-sort-problem-hgdm7?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue